# What is the most efficient way to allow users to order a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `note` model. A `user` has many `notes`. At the moment, the `notes` are ordered by `date`, and then by `created_at`.

I would like to give users the ability to order the notes (within a date) themselves.

For instance, if this is how they are currently displayed:

```
Date1
    note1,note2,note3
Date2
    note4
Date3
    note5,note6
```

The user could reorder them as follows:

```
Date1
    note3,note1,note2
Date2
    note4
Date3
    note6,note5
```

What is the most efficient way to implement this in Rails? Should I used a linked list? Or something else?

I'm using Rails 3.0.1 and Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to do this directly in the Model and let the database handle the ordering so I usually add a order_by field. When the user reorders the list the code simply tweaks the order_by field to reflect the new ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i would give it a position attribute. Thus, initially :

note1 -> 1
note2 -> 2
note3 -> 3
note4 -> 4
note5 -> 5

If i want note5 to get a position of 2, i would just need to exchange the position attributes.